# Wrote something to git log accidently

Tags: git

I was checking my git log and accidently pressed some stuff like "sqwe" and it got added to the log, now when I do "git status" it shows me the following:

```
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   sqwe
```

How do I remove this junk from my git log and status? And what would happen if I dont remobe it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That just means the file exists - it hasn't been added to git.   If you don't want the file then just remove it.  Git will not add it to the commit unless you explicitly ask it to.

Answer (score 2):

It's just saying that there's a file called `sqwe` that's currently in your directory tree, that's not being tracked.  There's nothing actually written to the git log at this point.  In fact, as long as you don't explicitly (or implicitly, e.g. with an "`-a`" argument to `git commit`) add the file to your index, it won't ever get written to git.

Just remove the `sqwe` file and you're good.

Comment: Ah, I see. Funny how it created file from log haha. Thanks!

Comment: I get that a lot for whatever reason.  My git checkouts typically have a good collection of files in the root directory with names like `[qes` or `wq` or even funky ones with spaces and other not-typically-in-a-filename characters.

Answer (score 2):

`rm /path/to/sqwe`

Alternatively, on a clean branch: 
`git add .` followed by
`git reset --hard latestcommitSHA`